# How to set timeout for ProxyAgent?

Tags: python, twisted

The [client.Agent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html) class has a connection timeout argument:

```
agent = client.Agent(reactor, connectTimeout=timeout, pool=pool)
```

How can this timeout be set when using [client.ProxyAgent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.ProxyAgent.html)?

```
auth = base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))
headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = ["Basic " + auth.strip()]
endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
agent = client.ProxyAgent(endpoint, reactor=reactor, pool=pool)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TCP4ClientEndpoint` you pass to `ProxyAgent` can be initialized with a timeout.

```
auth = base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))
headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = ["Basic " + auth.strip()]
endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port, timeout=yourTimeout)
agent = client.ProxyAgent(endpoint, reactor=reactor, pool=pool)
```

This is supposing you want to set the timeout for connecting to the proxy.  If you wanted to set the timeout used by the proxy to connect to the upstream HTTP server, you can't control this.

Comment: Yes was trying to set timeout for the overall request, including upstream HTTP server. I found the default timeout too short.

Comment: The `connectTimeout` argument to `Agent` is not an overall request timeout.  It is just a timeout on the TCP connection attempt.  The code in my answer implements exactly the same thing.  If what you want is not a TCP connection attempt timeout, then I think your question is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have set this connection timeout and created a wrapper class with deferred timeouts to cancel a request when round trip takes too long

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [client.ProxyAgent](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0/twisted/web/client.py#L1313) doesn't have a connectTimeout property:

```
class ProxyAgent(_AgentBase):
    """
    An HTTP agent able to cross HTTP proxies.

    @ivar _proxyEndpoint: The endpoint used to connect to the proxy.

    @since: 11.1
    """

    def __init__(self, endpoint, reactor=None, pool=None):
        if reactor is None:
            from twisted.internet import reactor
        _AgentBase.__init__(self, reactor, pool)
        self._proxyEndpoint = endpoint


    def request(self, method, uri, headers=None, bodyProducer=None):
        """
        Issue a new request via the configured proxy.
        """
        # Cache *all* connections under the same key, since we are only
        # connecting to a single destination, the proxy:
        key = ("http-proxy", self._proxyEndpoint)

        # To support proxying HTTPS via CONNECT, we will use key
        # ("http-proxy-CONNECT", scheme, host, port), and an endpoint that
        # wraps _proxyEndpoint with an additional callback to do the CONNECT.
        return self._requestWithEndpoint(key, self._proxyEndpoint, method,
                                         _URI.fromBytes(uri), headers,
                                         bodyProducer, uri)
```

`ProxyAgent` inherits from the same class `Agent` does (`_AgentBase`) and not from `Agent` itself.

Comment: that's a pity, so seems would need to create a new class to support this

Comment: A new class doesn't help.  Notice there are no calls to any `reactor.connectXXX` methods in `ProxyAgent`.  There's nowhere for you to add a connection timeout - except in the endpoint, as I explained in my answer.